# Solve integral using Plancherel's formula

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

This is from a test in Fourier analysis:

> Define $$ f(\xi)=\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\rm{sin}(\xi x) \rm{d}x $$ Calculate
>   $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2 \rm{d}x $$

I started with Plancherel's formula, i.e.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2 \rm{d}x = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(\xi)|^2 \rm{d}\xi
$$

but what now? Am I supposed to compute the integral of $f(\xi)$ somehow or what should I do?

Comment: Find $\mathrm{f}$ (for that you don't need to compute any integral).

Comment: @L.G.. Could you elaborate a little for me ? I am just curious and totally ignorant in this (and many many other) domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added the "idea flow" to the solution.. I don't know maybe it's useful.

> The idea is that the definition of $f(\xi)$ looks remarkably similar
>   to the definition of the Fourier transform. We want to calculate the
>   $2$-norm of $f(\xi)$, and we want to use Plancherel's theorem; So we
>   need to make Fourier transform come into play somehow. You note that
>   if the function you're integrating is odd, then the $\cos x$ part in
>   the Fourier transform vanishes; so we

Define $\sqrt x$ in $(-1, 1)$ so that it is an odd function. It's fourier transform is

$$\mathcal F (t)  = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt x e^{ixt} dx = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt x \cos(tx) dx + i \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt x \sin(tx) dx = 2i \int_0^1 \sqrt x \sin(tx) dx = 2if(t)$$

Now $\mathcal F$ and our modified $\sqrt x$ have the same $||\cdot||_2$ norm (plancherel's theorem!) , and you basically want to find $||\mathcal F||_2$.

You should be good to go now! :-)